# Removing unwanted extra space from unordered list in HTML

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have following code and I want to know how I can remove the extra space the browser puts when rendering.

```
<p> text text1 text 2</p>
<ul>
  <li>Bullet 1</li>
  <li>Bullet 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use CSS for lists.  This [page](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp) has a lot of resources and examples.